# How to chain actions in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

From research, I'm seeing that thunk is the tool you use to be able to chain actions together and/or deal with callbacks, asyc actions, and side-effects.

I'm having trouble understanding the [thunk middleware](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) guide. They reference 'store.dispatch' all the time (as do most tutorials on redux) yet I never actually call dispatch and never have access to 'store' so I'm unsure how to implement anything they propose.  (I assume this is because I use mapDispatchToProps in react.... which isn't an option in my action creators files)

Below is my action creator (some code removed to clarity):

```
import { CREATE_NEW_SAMPLING_EVENT } from '../Constants/ActionTypes';
import { emptySamplingEvent } from '../Constants/SamplingEvent';
import _ from 'lodash';
import uuidv4 from 'uuid';

export function createNewSamplingEvent(eventName) {
    let newEvent = _.cloneDeep(emptySamplingEvent);
    newEvent.eventID = uuidv4();
    newEvent.eventName = eventName;
    newEvent.dateModified = new Date();

    //TODO: call an optional callback 
    //TODO: dispatch eventLinkTable event

    return { type: CREATE_NEW_SAMPLING_EVENT, event: newEvent }
}
```

What I would like to do is listed in the 'todo's.

I have another action, called EVENT_LINK_TABLE in a different action creator file and different reducer, that would take the uuid from this action creator as an argument.  I'd like to dispatch this EVENT_LINK_TABLE action (with the uuid) as soon as I'm done making this a new event.

Further, I'd like to call a standard callback (which will actually be dispatching another action - LOAD_SAMPLNG_EVENT).. but I'm unsure how to call the callback AND return the action.  I'm also hearing that doing that from the action creator is bad practice, as well as I don't want it to happen if there is a failure in the creation process.

To add additional info, this is where I'm dispatching the action in my react code:\

```
handleBrandNewButtonClick = () => {
    this.props.createNewSamplingEvent(this.state.newSamplingEventName);
}
```

This component is 'connect'ed thusly:

```
const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
    return {
        samplingEvents: state.SamplingEvents, //to get list of sampling events to check for uniqueness for that user
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    createNewSamplingEvent,
}

export default withRouter(
    withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })
        (connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
            (NewEventForm)
        )
);
```

Comment: I think you're interpreting redux incorrectly. Before you think about using middleware, make sure you understand vanilla redux first. Your code is structured in a way that makes it pretty thunk unfriendly. Keep action creators slim and keep the business logic in the action itself

Comment: The action, itself, is `{ type: CREATE_NEW_SAMPLING_EVENT, event: newEvent }` ... is that not thin enough?   The next item on the redux workflow is the reducer, which isn't allowed to have side-effects.  If I can't have it in the action, and can't have it in the reducer...I'm unsure where I'd put any sort of actual logic.

Comment: What resource told you to not put any logic inside an action? Because that is many levels of wrong. The entire point of thunk is to give you a lot of options to put logic inside an action

Comment: https://redux.js.org/introduction/core-concepts -- "An action is a plain JavaScript object (notice how we don’t introduce any magic?) that describes what happened."
Also see Dilshan's answer below - "Actions creators should only return plain objects" (the implication being those plain objects are the actions)

Comment: I can see your source of confusion. That statement is very poorly written. Yes, actions are objects, but nothing is stopping you from making a function with business logic that eventually runs an action. Let me go further into detail

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have proper knowledge in redux. I'll tell you how redux store works. Then you will be able to understand redux.

In redux, we have five things,

Action creator, Action, Dispatcher, Reducers, Store

Imagine you thought to open an insurance company. Ok, here we have our first client. He came to the company and ask for, 'Hey I need to open a new account'.

Now the front desk person will say, 'Ok fill this form and give it to me' Once he gave the form to the front desk, then the person can leave.

1. In redux, this person is known as Action Creator
2. The form itself know as the object that returns from action creator
3. The front-desk person know as Dispatcher

Once the dispatcher got the form, he will make some photocopies of it and send to all departments in your company. policy department, Accounting department, Claims department, etc

1. These departments are known as reducers

Now each department will check what kind of form is this. Or it's about opening a new account. Ok, Accounting department will get the sum of money and add it to the company vault. Also, the policy department will make a new account for the client. But, the Claims department will not care about this form because it is not about a claim. This is why we set a 'type' property to the object.

Actions creators should only return **plain objects**. For example, if there is an async call in the action creator it does not return a plain object so we need to have some middleware to avoid this problem. Here we have redux-thunk. This middleware will help us to manually do the dispatch process.

So we get the dispatcher as the parameter to the action creator. Then, once we get the results from the async process, now we can dispatch the results manually inside that action creator. This redux thunk act as a middleware between the dispatcher and the reducers.

Answer (score 0):

You can run business logic inside a function and `dispatch` the action itself. The action creator, `setNewsCreator` creates a POJO. That POJO is then `dispatch`ed as an action that will get picked up by the reducer

```
// action creator
const setNewsCreator = ({ news }) => ({ type: 'SET_NEWS', news })

const fetchNews = () => async dispatch => { 
    const response = await getNews()
    dispatch(setNewsCreator({ news: response }))
}
```

and its usage in a component

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchNews() // assuming you've added this function to your mapDispatchToProps
}
```

Apologies for my first comment. In hindsight, I was not explaining actions correctly.

Comment: If you have any questions on the syntax I use, feel free to ask